# Calculating better value products.

Tags: products, percentages

The special promotion tins of 300g cost 0.80$.

The soup can also be bought in larger tin of 500g that cost 1.12$.

Is it better value to buy the 500g tin or the special promotion tin?
Show your working.

Comment: Consider price per gram. For promotion tins this is $80/300=0.27$c per g. For the large tin this is $112/500=0.22$c per gram. Since $0.22 \leq 0.27$ the large tin is better value.

Answer (score 0):

$(300,500)=1500$

And:

$5*0.8>3*1.12$

So in general it's better to buy the 500g tin